# Error establishing MongoDB connection on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to connect mongodb with my server but not connecting. If anyone know how to solve the issue please let me know
Here is my connection code:

```
mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/dating", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected");
    app.use(express.json());
    app.listen(3000);
    app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
  })
  .catch(() => {
    console.log("Error establishing db connection");
  });
```

MongoDB compass running on localhost:

Comment: What is the error message? Message `Error establishing db connection` does not help so much.

Comment: reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined
}

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: Please edit your question for such additional information instead of putting it into a comment. Did you start the Mongo database?

Comment: Can you please mention which version of MongoDB are you trying to connect?